# Storm KafkaBolt push to multiple Kafka Topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have a use-case, where I have a message which has to be pushed to a number of kafka topics.
Currently at a high level, that method looks like this:

```
pushToTopics(String msg){
  pushToTopicA(msg);
  pushToTopicB(msg);
  pushToTopicC(msg);
  .
  .
  .
  pushToTopicN(msg);
}
```

Every PushToTopicX(msg) has a condition which when fulfilled should lead the message to be published to the corresponding topic. Right now, all of this logic is at the terminal Bolt and to push the messages, we use KafkaProducer.

I was looking at ways to break this down into topic specific bolts and more importantly use KafkaBolts to push messages.

Is it possible with storm(v 1.2.2)? I saw that very recently a PR has been merged which lets one create custom callbacks, but we don't have that.

Comment: Are you looking for some class design for your logic?

Answer (score 0):

The KafkaBolt can decide which [topic to send to](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/730c1a302d857121542ce27b6a40b05b90f7f3ed/external/storm-kafka-client/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/kafka/bolt/selector/KafkaTopicSelector.java) based on the tuple. You could just use a splitter bolt to split your message into `N` messages, each with a different destination topic, and then send all of them to the KafkaBolt.

Answer (score 0):

The way I eventually solved it is to create separate streams, each one bound to the destination topics. Then via collector.emit on specific streams, I was able to fan the messages out across various bolts, which eventually push to Kafka using KafkaBolt.